# Defining setf for function in closure

Tags: lisp, closures, common-lisp

If I create a closure like this,

```
(let ((A (make-array '(10) :initial-element 5)))    
  (defun h (i)
    (aref a i))
  (defsetf h (i) (x) `(setf (aref ,a ,i) ,x)))
```

then, as I expect,  `(h i)` will return the i-th element of `a`:

```
(h 1)  ;; => 5
(h 2)  ;; => 5
```

Butalthough the `setf` expansion semes to work and correctly set the i-th element of `a`, it also produces a warning in SBCL:

```
(setf (h 1) 10)

; in: SETF (H 1)
;     (SETF (AREF #(5 10 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5) 1) #:G1124)
; --> LET* MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND LET FUNCALL SB-C::%FUNCALL 
; ==>
;   ((SETF AREF) #:NEW0 #(5 10 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5) 1)
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   Destructive function (SETF AREF) called on constant data.
;   See also:
;     The ANSI Standard, Special Operator QUOTE
;     The ANSI Standard, Section 3.2.2.3
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

In GCL an error is signalled:

```
>(setf (h 1) 10)

Error: 
Fast links are on: do (si::use-fast-links nil) for debugging
Signalled by LAMBDA-CLOSURE.
Condition in LAMBDA-CLOSURE [or a callee]: INTERNAL-SIMPLE-UNBOUND-VARIABLE: Cell error on A: Unbound variable: 

Broken at LIST.  Type :H for Help.
    1  Return to top level.
```

In CLISP and ECL, the example works just fine.

I am returning to Common Lisp after writing Scheme for a couple of years, so I may be mixing the two languages, conceptually. I suppose I have triggered behavior that is undefined according to the spec, but I can't see exactly what I did wrong. I would appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Problem

It is often instructive to try [`macroexpand`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm):

```
(macroexpand '(setf (h 2) 7))
==>
(LET* ()
  (MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND (#:G655)
      7
    (SETF (AREF #(5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5) 2) #:G655)))
```

As you can see, your `setf` call expands into a form which calls `setf` on a literal array which is a bad idea in general and, in fact, this is precisely what SBCL is warning you about:

```
Destructive function (SETF AREF) called on constant data.
```

Note that despite the warning SBCL (and other conformant implementations like CLISP and ECL) will do what you expect them to do.
This is because the literal array is referred to by the local variable which is accessible to the function `h`.

### Solution

I suggest that you use a function instead

```
(let ((A (make-array '(10) :initial-element 5)))
  (defun h (i)
    (aref a i))
  (defun (setf h) (x i)
    (setf (aref a i) x)))
```

Comment: I see -- you're right. I wonder then why CLISP and ECL let me change the value, and gave me 10 when I issued `(h 1)` after the `setf`...